# Reading and copying large files/blobs without storing them in memory stream in C#

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, memorystream

below is the code which reads the blobs from my blob storage and then copy the contents in a tabular storage. Everything works fine now. but I know that if my file is too big then it will fail this reading and copying. I would like to know how do we handle this ideally, is it we write the file temporarily instead of storing it in memory? If yes , can someone give me example or show me how to do it in my existing code below >

```
public async Task<Stream> ReadStream(string containerName, string digestFileName, string fileName, string connectionString)
        {
            string data = string.Empty;
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            var contents = await DownloadBlob(containerName, digestFileName, connectionString);
                           
            return contents;
        }

    public async Task<Stream> DownloadBlob(string containerName, string fileName, string connectionString)
    {        

       Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        if (!blob.Exists())
        {
            throw new Exception($"Unable to upload data in table store for document");
        }
       
        return await blob.OpenReadAsync();  
}

     private IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>> ReadCSV(Stream source, IEnumerable<TableField> cols)
    {
        
            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(source, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
            
                var cache = new TypeConverterCache();
                cache.AddConverter<float>(new CSVSingleConverter());
                cache.AddConverter<double>(new CSVDoubleConverter());
                var csv = new CsvReader(reader,
                    new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    {
                        Delimiter = ";",
                        HasHeaderRecord = true,
                        CultureInfo = global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        TypeConverterCache = cache
                    });
                csv.Read();
                csv.ReadHeader();


                var map = (
                        from col in cols
                        from src in col.Sources()
                        let index = csv.GetFieldIndex(src, isTryGet: true)
                        where index != -1
                        select new { col.Name, Index = index, Type = col.DataType }).ToList();

                while (csv.Read())
                {
                    yield return map.ToDictionary(
                        col => col.Name,
                        col => EntityProperty.CreateEntityPropertyFromObject(csv.GetField(col.Type, col.Index)));
                }
            
            }
        
    }
```

Comment: Where is the bit that "copy the contents in a tabular storage"? Also, think about streams - they're like pipes, you have something you want to read from and something you want to write to. Right now you use the methods where you give the blockblob a memorystream and it writes to it, then you (probably) reset it and give it to the tableblob and get it to read from it.. but why not just ask the blockblob for its stream and give that stream to the table blob and get it to read from it? This is pretty much the whole idea of a stream; they're just a flow of data. You're still thinking of it all...

Comment: ... in terms of "I have to read all the data, I have to put it somewhere, I have to write it..." - instead think about how to stream data around by giving "the thing that wants to read" a direct connection to the "thing that wants to supply data to be read" (or equally giving "the thing that wants to be written to" a direct connection to "the thing that wants to write" without standing in the middle and doing the reading/writing into/out of a temporary store (memory or disk)

Comment: thats something I am looking for and reading and writing it temporarily was my idea..but you understand what issue am talking here, do you have any example for refrence . I edited the code where I am reading the data passed from ReadStream()

Comment: More confused now. Thought you were talking about azure table storage.. you seem to be talking about downloading a blockblob and converting it to CSV but you've posted two read methods; I would expect a read and a write. The concept remains the same; if you have "something that supplies a stream you can read from" (="something you can supply with a stream that it will write to") and you have "something that supplies a stream you can write to" (="something you can supply with a stream that it will read from") then you can pair them up and have them do the read/write directly without temp storag

Comment: Ok, What I am doing here is reading blobs from azure blob storage, the blobs are bascially csv files and I am copying the contents in a Azure Tabular storage. I have not provided the method where it is inserting the data to tabular storage but thats a basically taking all ReadCsv data and inserting them in table batch wise. I am not finding anything that supplies a stream for  azure blobs. any idea if that is supported for blobs

Comment: [CloudBlockBlock.OpenRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/jj717626(v%3dazure.10)) perhaps? It "supplies a stream for reading from the blob", and CsvReader reads from a TextReader which is the abstract parent of eg a StreamReader which reads from a stream (supplied by the blob, for example) so you've get CsvReader to read from a StreamReader that reads from the blob stream

Comment: can you please modify my code on what you mentioned below and post it as an answer. I am unable to make it work with openRead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your insistence that CsvHelper is incapable of reading from a stream connected to a blob, I threw something together:

- WinForms core app (3.1)
- CsvHelper latest (19)
- Azure.Storage.Blobs (12.8)

A CSV from my disk:

[image]

On my blob storage:

[image]

In my debugger, it has record CAf255 OK by Read/GetRecord:

[image]

Or by EnumerateRecords:

[image]

Using this code:

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cstr = "MY CONNECTION STRING HERE";

        var bbc = new BlockBlobClient(cstr, "temp", "call.csv");

        var s = await bbc.OpenReadAsync(new BlobOpenReadOptions(true) { BufferSize = 16384 });

        var sr = new StreamReader(s);

        var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(sr, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) { HasHeaderRecord = true });

        var x = new X();

        //try by read/getrecord (breakpoint and skip over it if you want to try the other way)
        while(await csv.ReadAsync())
        {
            var rec = csv.GetRecord<X>();
            Console.WriteLine(rec.Sid);
        }

        //try by await foreach
        await foreach (var r in csv.EnumerateRecordsAsync(x))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r.Sid);
        }
    }
```

Oh, and the class that represents a CSV record in my app (I only modeled one property, Sid, to prove the concept):

```
class X {
    public string Sid{ get; set; }
}
```

Maybe dial things back a bit, start simple. One string prop in your CSV, no yielding etc, just get the file reading in OK. I didn't bother with all the header faffing either - seems to just work OK by saying "file has headers" in the options - you can see my debugger has an instance of X with a correctly populated Sid property showing the first value. I ran some more loops and they populated OK too

Comment: thanks, i am trying all mentioned here. thanks a lot

Comment: i did you way and though there is no error popping out from your method above, it does not hit the code inside while loop and foreach loop. something with async issue?? Also what is new BlobOpenReadOptions(true) { BufferSize = 16384 }. I am not able to resolve this

Comment: As you can see, from the screenshot of a CSV on my computer, the screenshot of my Azure Storage Explorer showing it uploaded to blob storage, and the screenshot of my visual studio debugger having downloaded the file, parsed it to csv and entered a loop where it is showing the parsed content, I'm not really sure what I can do to convince you that the code works - take a screen recording of me single stepping the debugger perhaps?

Comment: I figured out BlobOptionRead issue, i was not referring the right version but the issue remains, the code does not go inside foreach or while loop

Comment: Then there are no records?

Comment: the file is there, the stream sr has length and position as well

Comment: `Console.WriteLIne(sr.ReadToEnd())` should print the entire file, so debug why your Csv reader isn't reading it. My CsvReader reads my file, and it even reads your file (when i copied and saved your data using notepad). Use a different CSV file, check the line endings etc

Comment: finally figured out it was my mistake, where StreamReader was reading the stream and setting position to be last of stream instead of zero and that was the reason earlier method was not working. removed the streamreader and now everything works fine. thanks for your help. guys like you are the reason, stackoverflow is so successful.

Comment: You(your code) doesn't read from the streamreader at all or set the position of the stream directly ;  you just get a stream, wrap a streamreader around it and give the streamreader to csvreader - it does all the reading and positioning. If you read a stream all the way to the end and then give it to something else to read, there is nothing left for the "something else" to read

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it could look something like this (modify your ReadCSV to take a stream, not lines):

```
private IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>> ReadCSV(Stream source, IEnumerable<TableField> cols)
{
    using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(source))
```

And this (modify your DownloadBlob to instead return a stream):

```
public async Task<Stream> GetBlobStream(string containerName, string fileName, string connectionString)
    {
        
        Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        if (!blob.Exists())
        {
            throw ...
        }
            
        return await blob.OpenReadAsync();

    }
```

And then wire them together:

```
var stream = GetBlobStream(...)

ReadCSV(stream, ...)
```

Comment: I thought the aim here was to avoid reading a massive file into memory. What do you think `data = streamReader.ReadToEnd()` is going to do?

Comment: Where do you think the contents of the `data` variable live?

Comment: :D yep.. so the idea is: we get a stream to the blob, we give the stream to the csv reader, we read a bit from the reader, which pulls a bit from the stream (hopefully it will do that and not do a ReadToEnd internally), and as we are read read reading bit by bit from the reader, we are pushing into azure table storage... and we never use much memory

Comment: then what about encoding utf8? Is that required if I pass stream to ReadCSV(), I will need to address that as well

Comment: You can specify an encoding when you [create the StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_) but UTF8 is the default anyway

Comment: Note that UTF8 is the deault anyway so you don't need to do anything specific for it

Comment: hi...tried it but recieving error on line csv.ReadHeader() as "No header record was found." at CsvHelper.CsvReader.ParseNamedIndexes()
   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.ReadHeader().  the headers is there and am able to read when reading as MemoryStream.

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging then and see what it's doing...

Comment: modified the question with latest code, I am guessing the parsing is not happening as it should be

Comment: Download the code of CsvHelper and add it as a project, reference it.. THis way you can debugger step into the code and see how it is behaving

Comment: it seems csv helper do not read the stream returned from openreadasync(). any alternative approach with filestream?

Comment: It doesn't make sense; it will read from the reader that reads from the memory stream but not read from the reader that reads from the network stream? CsvHelper doesn't know about the stream, it only knows about the reader

Comment: its weird but thats what has been happening. i posted this as a seperate question and people are suggesting that this csvhelper limitation here that it is not reading network stream..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65442508/csvhelper-error-no-header-record-found-on-reading-a-csv-stream/65442781?noredirect=1#comment115728699_65442781

Comment: Did you read it from blob. can you please paste your code as what you tried

Comment: Yes, I read it from a blob. I'm just writing an answer with the exact code