# CsvHelper Error "No header record found" on reading a csv stream

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Below is the code which i using to read a stream source of csv files but I get error as "No header record found". The library is 15.0 and I am already using .ToList() as suggested in some solutions, but still the error persists. Below is the method along with the tablefield class and the Read Stream method.

Also note here, I can get the desired result if I pass source as MemoryStream but it fails if I pass it as Stream because I need to avoid writing to memory each time.

```
public async Task<Stream> DownloadBlob(string containerName, string fileName, string connectionString)
        {
            //  MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();           

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            {
                connectionString = @"UseDevelopmentStorage=true";
                containerName = "testblobs";
            }

            Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            if (!blob.Exists())
            {
                throw new Exception($"Blob Not found");
            }
          
            return await blob.OpenReadAsync();



public class TableField
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public Type DataType
        {
            get
            {
                switch( Type.ToUpper() )
                {
                    case "STRING":
                        return typeof(string);

                    case "INT":
                        return typeof( int );

                    case "BOOL":
                    case "BOOLEAN":
                        return typeof( bool );

                    case "FLOAT":
                    case "SINGLE":
                    case "DOUBLE":
                        return typeof( double );

                    case "DATETIME":
                        return typeof( DateTime );

                    default:
                        throw new NotSupportedException( $"CSVColumn data type '{Type}' not supported" );
                }
            }
        }

 private IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>> ReadCSV(Stream source, IEnumerable<TableField> cols)           

 {                
         using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(source, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                
                    var cache = new TypeConverterCache();
                    cache.AddConverter<float>(new CSVSingleConverter());
                    cache.AddConverter<double>(new CSVDoubleConverter());
                    var csv = new CsvReader(reader,
                        new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        {
                            Delimiter = ";",
                            HasHeaderRecord = true,
                            CultureInfo = global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            TypeConverterCache = cache
                        });
                    csv.Read();
                    csv.ReadHeader();


                    var map = (
                            from col in cols
                            from src in col.Sources()
                            let index = csv.GetFieldIndex(src, isTryGet: true)
                            where index != -1
                            select new { col.Name, Index = index, Type = col.DataType }).ToList();

                    while (csv.Read())
                    {
                        yield return map.ToDictionary(
                            col => col.Name,
                            col => EntityProperty.CreateEntityPropertyFromObject(csv.GetField(col.Type, col.Index)));
                    }
                
                }
            
        }
```

StreamReading code:

```
public async Task<Stream> ReadStream(string containerName, string digestFileName, string fileName, string connectionString)
        {
            string data = string.Empty;
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            var contents = await DownloadBlob(containerName, digestFileName, connectionString);               
                
            
            return contents;
        }
```

Sample CSv to be read:

```
PartitionKey;Time;RowKey;State;RPM;Distance;RespirationConfidence;HeartBPM
te123;2020-11-06T13:33:37.593Z;10;1;8;20946;26;815
te123;2020-11-06T13:33:37.593Z;4;2;79944;8;36635;6
te123;2020-11-06T13:33:37.593Z;3;3;80042;9;8774;5
te123;2020-11-06T13:33:37.593Z;1;4;0;06642;6925;37
te123;2020-11-06T13:33:37.593Z;6;5;04740;74753;94628;21
te123;2020-11-06T13:33:37.593Z;7;6;6;2;14;629
te123;2020-11-06T13:33:37.593Z;9;7;126;86296;9157;05
te123;2020-11-06T13:33:37.593Z;5;8;5;3;7775;08
te123;2020-11-06T13:33:37.593Z;2;9;44363;65;70;229
te123;2020-11-06T13:33:37.593Z;8;10;02;24666;2;2
```

Comment: You don't appear to have included the source code to downloadBlob, nor clearly explained that the source csv is on azure blob storage. Adding a link to your related other question would be sensible too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to my [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/115731951) (it has more detail ; you can read it there) I didn't encounter any problem connecting CsvHelper to a blob storage sourced stream

[image]

This was the code used (I took the CSV data you posted, added it to a file, upped it to blob):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cstr = "YOUR CONNSTR" HERE;

        var bbc = new BlockBlobClient(cstr, "temp", "ankit.csv");

        var s = await bbc.OpenReadAsync(new BlobOpenReadOptions(true) { BufferSize = 16384 });

        var sr = new StreamReader(s);

        var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(sr, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) { HasHeaderRecord = true, Delimiter = ";" });

        
        //try by read/getrecord
        while(await csv.ReadAsync())
        {
            var rec = csv.GetRecord<X>();
            Console.WriteLine(rec.PartitionKey);
        }

        var x = new X();
        //try by await foreach
        await foreach (var r in csv.EnumerateRecordsAsync(x))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r.PartitionKey);
        }
    }
}

class X {
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to reproduce the problem with version 15.0 of the library, but have failed with classes `CSVSingleConverter` and `CSVDoubleConverter`. With the standard classes of the CSVHelper, however, reading the header works:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.TypeConversion;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"e:\demo.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                ReadCSV(stream);
            }
        }

        private static void ReadCSV(Stream source)

        {
            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(source, Encoding.UTF8))
            {

                var cache = new TypeConverterCache();
                cache.AddConverter<float>(new SingleConverter());
                cache.AddConverter<double>(new DoubleConverter());
                var csv = new CsvReader(reader,
                    new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    {
                        Delimiter = ";",
                        HasHeaderRecord = true,
                        CultureInfo = global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        TypeConverterCache = cache
                    });
                csv.Read();
                csv.ReadHeader();

                foreach (string headerRow in csv.Context.HeaderRecord)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(headerRow);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I´ve changed the lines ...

```cs
cache.AddConverter<float>(new CSVSingleConverter());
cache.AddConverter<double>(new CSVDoubleConverter());
```

... to ...

```cs
cache.AddConverter<float>(new SingleConverter());
cache.AddConverter<double>(new DoubleConverter());
```

I put the CSV data into a UTF-8 text file. Output at the console is:

```
PartitionKey
Time
RowKey
State
RPM
Distance
RespirationConfidence
HeartBPM
```

**EDIT 2020-12-24:**
Put the whole source text online, not just part of it.

Comment: I tried the same as you said but I get the same error. you sure you didnt change anything else? How are you passing the source?

Comment: modified the question as how I am reading the stream and passing it to ReadCsv(). I believe you used MemoryStream(). It works fine with Memory stream, but I have avoid reading to Memory as it will create problem for large files.

Comment: @AnkitKumar I will update my answer and post the full source code. In fact, I have adapted more or removed (supposedly) unneeded parts. However, I did not use MemeoryStream, but FileStream.

Comment: please try as I did and am sure you will get the same error

Comment: @AnkitKumar Ok, I´ll try. What are 'TableField' and 'EntityProperty'? From were can I get this types?

Comment: @AnkitKumar Sorry, but I didn´t get this error. I´ve also tried it with .NET Framework 4.6.2 and .NET Core. Both are working. Which stream type do you use?

Comment: I used System.IO.Stream(). I have update dthe question with tableFeild Class.. You can see the question readstream(), the "contents " stream which is returned is passed a "source" in readCsv()

Comment: @AnkitKumar Have you checked what is in this stream? Have you written the contents to a file? Somehow I suspect the problem is there.

Comment: I get the length and positions of the contents and yes If i do  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(contents, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                } I read the actual content in data

Comment: I believe you are still going for FileStream. i am actually here reading a blob from Azureblob storage by using blob.OpenReadAsync(); method and it returns a Task object of type stream

Comment: @AnkitKumar Yes, of course I still use FileStream. I don't have Azure available. ;) It would be interesting to know which derived stream type is hidden behind your stream. What do CanRead, CanSeek say? It is possible that CsvReader cannot handle this type of your stream. Have you tried updating to the latest CsvHelper version?

Comment: Saber, can you please elaborate more How you are asking me to check on CanRead() and CanSeek() functionality? You might be right that CsvHelper do not support this but then the question is CsvHelper was able to read MemoryStream then it shouldnt be issue with Stream object. I will check with updating latest version of CsvHelper.

Comment: @AnkitKumar System.IO.Stream is merely an abstract base class. There are many concrete implementations, for example MemoryStream or FileStream. But not all of these derived implementations behave identically. For example, a stream can be readonly, in which case the CanWrite property is "false". Other streams do not support the shifting of the position pointer, in which case CanSeek would be "false". If your logic works with FileStream and MemoryStream, this is rather an indication that CsvHelper does not deal with the type of stream. At least that's my guess.

Comment: MemoryStream works meant, I am able to actually read the content put them in memory and then pass the actual content in TextReader. In that case it works...and that basically the same thing with FileStream where you are writing in a temporary file. I believe maybe you are right about Csvhelper. I tried with latest version and error is same. If someone from CSVhelper team could confirm this.

Comment: Counter question: is temporary caching as a memory stream a problem in your scenario?

Comment: What you meant here?? Temporary cache??

Comment: @AnkitKumar You wrote that you get a correct position/length from the Azure stream and that you can read the content correctly via ReadToEnd(). Correct? - Since this works, you can use this functionality, read out the data and then write it temporarily to a memory stream to make it available to CsvHelper. Depending on the application scenario, this can (under certain circumstances) be a useful workaround.

Comment: that was exactly i was doing earlier, and the reason i dont want to do that is because the files are going to be large and writing each time in memory is not an ideal solution. there will be situation where  code throws into memory exception

Comment: In that case, use a FileStream instead of a MemoryStream. :-) Otherwise, without new information, I can only guess. Finally, I can advise you to take a closer look at the stream type and, in the case of asynchronous processing, check whether all relevant data for CsvHelper are really available when reading starts.

Comment: i read the length and position of the stream in the first line of Readcsv() method..so it does read the data

Comment: just to give more insight here, i have now added the downloadblob method in the question , it is the blob.openreadasync() which returns stream passed in readcsv()

Comment: Have you checked Caius Jard's answer yet? It seems to work there too, so maybe you should try his code.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the source stream back to the start.

```cs
private IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>> ReadCSV(Stream source, IEnumerable<TableField> cols)           
{    
   source.Position = 0;
```

You also can't use `yield return` there. It delays execution of the code until you access the `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>>` returned from the `ReadCSV` method. The problem is at that point you have already closed the using statement with the `TextReader` that `CsvHelper` needs to read your data, so you get a `NullReferenceException`.

You either need to remove the `yield return`

```cs
var result = new List<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>>();
while (csv.Read()){
   // Add to result
}
return result;
```

Or pass the `TextReader` to your method. Any enumaration of the `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>>` must occur before leaving the using statement which will dispose of the `TextReader` needed by the `CsvReader`

```cs
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>> result;

using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(source, Encoding.UTF8)){
   // Calling ToList() will enumerate your yield statement
   result = ReadCSV(reader, cols).ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: i get System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: That is likely another issue.  You can't use `yield return` there.  It delays execution of the code until you access the `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>>` returned from the `ReadCSV` method.  The problem is at that point you have already closed the using statement with the `TextReader` that `CsvHelper` needs to read your data, so you get a `NullReferenceException`.  You either need to remove the `yield return` or pass the `TextReader` to your method and destroy it after iterating over the `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>>`

Comment: Can you please elaborate more with the code and show me what you meant by destroying textReader

Comment: @AnkitKumar I added some more code.  When you call `ReadCSV` it returns an `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>>` to you.  Unfortunately, you have also left the `using(){ }` statement then and it automatically disposes the `TextReader`.  When you later iterate the `IEnumerable` and `yield return`, `CsvHelper` tries to use the `TextReader` that has already been disposed.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error 'No header found...' and this was after several hundred successful reads of the same file. I added the delimiter=","

reader = csv.reader(filename, delimiter=",")

and that solved the problem. I think the csv_reader will attempt to determine the delimiter if the delimiter is not specified, and fails after a while, maybe a memory leak? the comma is the default, but if the reader has to programatically determine it, it is more likely to fail.